# How to make my overlay about 70% height and on the bottom?

Tags: html, jquery, css, loadingoverlay

I need to make an overlay and unfortunately it seems like I can only do it using an external lib.
Been using this one https://gasparesganga.com/labs/jquery-loading-overlay/ and it's almost perfect!
I just need to make it about 70% height and attached to the bottom of the page.

```
$.LoadingOverlay("show", {
                    background  : " rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                    text: "Text!",
                    image: "",
                    textColor: "#ffffff",
                });
```

I can kinda "override" the css and get the height but not attached to the bottom because the original css has a top:0 ...

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: How about [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.BusyIndicator) or simply setting the busy state of your view to true?

Comment: @Marc it does not relay the message I want and visually it does not look good on my application...

Comment: If it does not relay your message then that's not the fault of the control but your code flow. And it's the SAP standard so while it might not look good to you personally it fits to the rest of your application. Using custom css/jquery is always a bad idea.

Comment: We make custom web apps. And using the busy state does not achieve my goal at all.

Comment: What's your goal then?

Comment: FYI: please take **accessibility** also into consideration when implementing your own busy indicator (focus handling, screen reader, color contrast, ...). Existing SAPUI5 controls in the Horizon theme are already compliant to WCAG standards.

Comment: @Marc it's having a simple overlay with a text. The user needs to fill something before using the form.

Comment: Then use a [Dialog with confirm options](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Dialog/sample/sap.m.sample.DialogConfirm)?

Comment: @Marc I appreciate your answers but this isn't anything like what I said I wanted.

Comment: @BlueHeart I removed the [sapui5] tag since the question is not expecting any solution from the UI5 framework.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```js
$.LoadingOverlay('show', {
                    background  : " rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                    text: "Text!",
                    image: "",
                    textColor: "#ffffff",
                });
$('.loadingoverlay').css({'top':'30%', 'height':'70%'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-loading-overlay@2.1.7/dist/loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>


 <h1>This is H1<h1>
 <div>This is text on page...</div>
 <div>This is more<br>text<br>on page...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly like that! :)